# How can i select data between April 2014 and March 2015

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Named Product_Sales and it holds data like this

```
Product_ID | Sold_by | Qty | month      | year
-----------+---------+-----+------------+-----------
3          | 12      | 7   |     4      | 2014
6          | 22      | 14  |     5      | 2014
8          | 11      | 9   |     3      | 2015
```

How can i select data between from_date as April 2014 and to_date as March 2015(4-2014 and 3-2015) in sql server
Thank you

Comment: You should probably consider changing the structure of your table so you store actual dates rather than a year and a month like that. But failing that, you just want to select things where `(YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH >= 4) OR (YEAR=2015 AND MONTH <=3)`

Comment: so if it's a where condition something like this WHERE CAST(month+'-01'+'-'+year,DATETIME) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-31'

Answer (score 0):

use multiple condition .

ie

```
         declare @todate smalldatetime 
         declare @fromdate smalldatetime 

         Select * from Product_Sales
         where ([YEAR] < DATEPART(yyyy, @todate) and [YEAR] > DATEPART(yyyy,  @fromdate) )
         or  (
                   ([YEAR] = DATEPART(yyyy,  @fromdate) and ( DATEPART(yyyy,  @fromdate) = DATEPART(yyyy,  @todate)) )
                   and ([month]  <= DATEPART(mm, @todate) and [month] >= DATEPART(mm,  @fromdate) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select the data:

```
Select * From Product_Sales Where (YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH >= 4) OR (YEAR=2015 AND MONTH <=3)
```

If your table is formatted as such,

[image]

Your query will produce such a result

[image]